# Missing 64-bit support xcode 12.4

Tags: xcode, flutter

I get two errors when trying to validate the app. it works fine in simulators.

App Store Connect Operation Error
Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support.

App Store Connect Operation Error
Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64.

Answer (score 1):

same to me. but it hard to get solution from web.
all the common answer about the Valid Architecture arm64.

But xcode 12 already take out the Valid Architecture =(